# Inner loop on condition in list comprehension

Tags: python, django, list-comprehension

I have a function to check availability of product and its variations. both model has `quantity_left` field.

If a product has variations i want to get `quantity_left` from variation, otherwise i will take `quantity_left` from product.

```
def check_quota(products):
    q_list = []
    for p in products:
        if p.has_variations:
            for v in p.variations:
                q_list.append(v.quantity_left)
        else:
            q_list.append(p.quantity_left)
    return sum(q_list)
```

So above function will return either `0` or `any number`. if it is `zero` means product sold out.

Above code is working fine, but i want to optimize this function using list comprehension.

I tried this but this doesn't seems to work.

```
return sum([v.quantity_left if p.has_variations else p.quantity_left for p in products for v in i.variations])
```

How can i apply `if p.has_variations` on inner loop.

**UPDATE**

suppose i have 3 products under shirt category

```
[
  {
    "name":"full sleve", 
    "has_variations": True, 
    "variations":[
       {
         "type": "S size", 
         "quantity_left": 3
       }, 
       {
         "type": "L size", 
         "quantity_left": 0
       }
     ]
  },
  {
    "name":"half sleve", 
    "has_variations": False, 
    "quantity_left": 0
  },
  {
    "name":"sleve less", 
    "has_variations": False, 
    "quantity_left": 10
  }
]

# it will return 13 means not sold out.
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Comment: you cannot use list comprehension easily here because you have a loop enabled only when a condition is met.

Comment: @cssko data added check update section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should do the trick.

```
def check_quota(products):
    return sum(sum(v.quantity_left for v in p.variations) if p.has_variations else p.quantity_left for p in products)
```

Without the actual data, or any example of input-desired output, it is hard to come up with a working solution. The above code is a *blind* translation.

---

*From your EDIT, it seems that you are working with dictionaries and not classes. If that is indeed the case, use the following instead:*

```
def check_quota(products):
    return sum(sum(v['quantity_left'] for v in p['variations']) if p['has_variations'] else p['quantity_left'] for p in products)
```

Comment: the data you added do not work with your function. The function is working with classes, your data are in a `dict`

Comment: Your code is working,  I tested it like `v['quantity_left']`.